# How to abstract a property attribute in an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I would want to abstract a value of a property in the below array. May I know how can I do with php?

```
print_r($array);

Array
(
   [0] => {property1: 'value12', property2: 'value12', property3: 'value13'}
   [1] => {property1: 'value21', property2: 'value22', property3: 'value23'}
)
```

May I know how to read the value of attribute property1 of each array?

Comment: is the value inside `Array[0]{...` an object or an array?

Comment: @caramba, object

Comment: https://3v4l.org/HatcX ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an **array with objects** this might be the way to go:

```
$myArrayWithObjects = [
    0 => (Object) ['property1' => 'value12', 'property2' => 'value12', 'property3' => 'value13'],
    1 => (Object) ['property1' => 'value21', 'property2' => 'value22', 'property3' => 'value23']
];

echo 'Array with Objects: ' . $myArrayWithObjects[1]->property3 . "\n";
// prints: Array with Objects: value23
```

you can loop over the "first array" and use the `object` like so:

```
foreach($myArrayWithObjects as $myObject) {
    echo 'Array with Objects foreach: ' . $myObject->property2 . "\n";
}
```

**if it is an array with arrays** go this way:

```
$myArray = [
    0 => ['property1' => 'value12', 'property2' => 'value12', 'property3' => 'value13'],
    1 => ['property1' => 'value21', 'property2' => 'value22', 'property3' => 'value23']
];

echo 'Array with arrays: ' . $myArray[1]['property3'] . "\n";
// prints: Array with arrays: value23
```

and the foreach loop for array with arrays accordingly:

```
foreach($myArray as $innerArray) {
    echo 'Array with arrays foreach: ' . $innerArray['property2'] . "\n";
}
```

you can play with it online here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b8f5740350278f811ab9f998b9501c154697abf

Comment: Maybe add an example using `foreach()` ? _"... of each array ?"_

Comment: @Syscall thanks for feedback! I've updated the answer